# Wordpress redirect to referring page after logging in

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, authentication

> ***Note:** I already created the same question in [Wordpress StackExchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/169704/redirect-to-referring-page-after-logging-in), but I didn't receive any responses! Sorry about that!*

I am not using any custom login plugins or any bespoke code. A few of my pages have got this bit of code in them at the very beginning.

```
<?php
    if(!is_user_logged_in())
        wp_redirect('/login/');
?>
```

So, this doesn't allow the users to view the page when not logged in. I have these pages bearing this bit of code:

```
/wp-content/my-theme/my-account/
/wp-content/my-theme/my-account/world.php
/wp-content/my-theme/my-account/subscription.php
/wp-content/my-theme/my-dashboard.php
/wp-content/my-theme/my-files.php
```

Now, when a user goes to any of the above pages, without logging in, it redirects to the login page, and when the user logs in, it lands them to the `my-account/` page.

I want to change the current scenario to make the user redirect to the referring page, where he came from. I tried the following things, which never worked.

#### Using a `HTTP_REFERRER`

In the `login/` form, I placed this bit of code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?>" />
```

#### Hacking `functions.php`

In the `functions.php`, I placed this bit of code:

```
if ( (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] != 'logout') || (isset($_POST['login_location']) && !empty($_POST['login_location'])) ) {
        add_filter('login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3);
        function my_login_redirect() {
                $location = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
                wp_safe_redirect($location);
                exit();
        }
}
```

**References:**

- [Redirect wordpress back to referring page after login](http://wpsnipp.com/index.php/functions-php/redirect-back-to-referring-page-after-login/)
- [WordPress Tip: Redirect to Previous Page After Login](https://longren.io/wordpress-tip-redirect-to-previous-page-after-login/)

---

I have also tried these and failed:

- [Redirecting users to referrer page after logging in using custom login form](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/94465/redirecting-users-to-referrer-page-after-logging-in-using-custom-login-form)
- [Redirect user to original url after login?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16004/redirect-user-to-original-url-after-login)

Nothing was working out. I am happy to provide further details if needed. Thanks in advance. `:)`

---

#### My work so far...

I have modified the code this way:

```
<?php
    if(!is_user_logged_in())
        wp_redirect('/login/?redirect_to=' . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
?>
```

This renders the login page this way:

```
/login.php?redirect_to=/my-account/subscription.php
```

This would be enough for me to authenticate and redirect. But I need to find the bit where the real redirection happens and I want to redirect it using the `redirect_to` parameter!

Comment: This may help you: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/125952/redirect-to-current-page-after-wordpress-login. Alternatively, you could store the redirect URL as a `session` variable.

Comment: @rnevius Where do I put the redirect code? That's my final question! `:(`

Comment: I'm confused...Is the last part of your code not working? It looks like it should work...

Comment: How about `wp_redirect( wp_login_url( get_permalink() ) );`?

Comment: Have you tried using the `query_vars` filter and then using `get_query_var("redirect_to")` in your login template?

Comment: @Anand Please guide me how do I do. I haven't done that! `:)`

Comment: Please see the following link : http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/query_vars . Once the `redirect_to` variable is added to the query_vars, you can then later access it in the template using `get_query_vars("redirect_to")`

Comment: @Anand, If you could see the current setup, I get the `redirect_url` through `GET` method. What next? If I enter the username and password, it goes to the `my-account/` page only, not to anything else. Where exactly could I find this redirection happening?

Comment: How are you populating the login form on login.php?

Comment: It is just a basic `<form>` tag, could be possibly copied from the `wp-login.php`...

Comment: Have you checked the server logs for any 404's? In your post you've mentioned that my-account folder resides in your theme folder and since the files are non WP, and unless you've got some rewrite rules setup, you'll need the full URL, `redirect_to=/wp-content/themes/your-theme/my-account/subscription.php` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65773/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-anand).

Comment: Check out this plugin, it allows redirecting to a specified location on login, or by using a get/post query value - https://wordpress.org/plugins/peters-login-redirect/

Comment: @benJ Peter's plugin doesn't work for my use case. Already tried. `:(`

Comment: What happened when you tried my method?

Comment: @rnevius No change, just goes to `my-account/` only! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The login process is handled via AJAX. The function posting the values isn't considering `redirect_to` . The following code in the JS file always redirects to /my-account. So now when the AJAX function returns, you can get the value of `redirect_to` hidden field and then redirect the user there.

```
window.location = "/my-account/";
```